# Row Count in Trailer Record

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I need to create a text file that contains a header row, multiple data rows (could be any number of rows once I put it to work), and a trailer row that includes the final row number, which is to be the number of data rows, plus 2 (the header and trailer).

I have been able to achieve the desired result with the following query, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way of handling the task?

My test query:

```
--SINGLE HEADER ROW
SELECT 'PH3', to_char('10000000')
FROM DUAL

UNION ALL

--MULTIPLE DATA ROWS
SELECT 'PD3', 'NO SSN'
FROM students s
WHERE s.schoolid = '999999'

UNION ALL

--SINGLE TRAILER ROW
SELECT 'PT3', to_char(count(*)+2)
FROM students s
WHERE s.schoolid = '999999'
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your current query.

Comment: I'd add field names, but functionally I don't see an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been able to achieve the desired result with the following query, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way of handling the task?

As far as I know, it is not documented anywhere than `UNION ALL` will generate rows in any particular order. Even if it appears *today* to always work as you expected.

As of myself, I would consider than, without a specific `ORDER BY` clause, any set operation will produce an unordered result.

So for the sake of your peace of mind (or of some future maintainer), I would go for an explicit ordering. Probably not more efficient, but guarantying to output your rows in the expected order:

```
SELECT "col1", "col2" FROM (

    SELECT 0 as "position", 'PH3' as "col1", to_char('10000000') as "col2"
    FROM DUAL

    UNION ALL

    --MULTIPLE DATA ROWS
    SELECT 1, 'PD3', 'NO SSN'
    FROM students s
    WHERE s.schoolid = '999999'

    UNION ALL

    --SINGLE TRAILER ROW
    SELECT 2, 'PT3', to_char(count(*)+2)
    FROM students s
    WHERE s.schoolid = '999999'

) ORDER BY "position";
```

---

And, if you really want to get rid of the two `SELECT` having the same `WHERE` clause, maybe you could use a CTE?

```
WITH data AS (SELECT 'NO SSN'
        FROM students s
        WHERE s.schoolid = '999999')

SELECT "col1", "col2" FROM (

    SELECT 0 as "position", 'PH3' as "col1", to_char('10000000') as "col2"
    FROM DUAL

    UNION ALL

    --MULTIPLE DATA ROWS
    SELECT 1, 'PD3', 'NO SSN'
    FROM data

    UNION ALL

    --SINGLE TRAILER ROW
    SELECT 2, 'PT3', to_char(count(*)+2)
    FROM data

) ORDER BY "position";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROWNUM to obtain the final count of rows produced by the query, as in the following:

```
SELECT rectype,
       case
         when rectype <> 'PT3' THEN ssn
         else to_char(rownum, 'TM9')
       end as ssn
FROM
(--SINGLE HEADER ROW
SELECT 'PH3' as rectype, to_char('10000000') as ssn
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
--MULTIPLE DATA ROWS
SELECT 'PD3' as rectype, 'NO SSN' as ssn
FROM students s
WHERE s.schoolid = '999999'
UNION ALL
--SINGLE TRAILER ROW
SELECT 'PT3' as rectype, NULL as ssn
FROM DUAL)
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/159431/8)

Share and enjoy.